# image augmentation went wrong

Tags: python-3.x, keras, deep-learning

I was trying to make image augmentation and see how it will affect the model but for some reason I got this error

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'ImageDataGenerator'
```

I'm using efficientNetb4 with adding my own classifier layer.

```
augment = ImageDataGenerator(horizontal_flip=True, vertical_flip=True, rotation_range=30, validation_split=0.15) 
train = augment.flow_from_directory(path, target_size=(380,380), batch_size=35, subset='training')
valid = augment.flow_from_directory(path, target_size=(380,380), batch_size=35, subset='validation')

base_model = keras.applications.EfficientNetB4(weights="imagenet",include_top=False, input_shape=(380, 380,3))

for layer in base_model.layers:
 layer.trainable = False

avg = keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(base_model.output)
output = keras.layers.Dense(3, activation="softmax")(avg)

model = keras.Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=output)

earlystopping = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', patience=3)
optimizer = keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.001, momentum=0.9, decay=0.0001)

model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",optimizer=optimizer,metrics=["accuracy"])
history = model.fit_generator(train, augment, validation_data=valid, epochs=25, verbose=2, callbacks=[earlystopping])
```

I think the problem is the `batch_size` i specified but couldn't understand shy it caused this error

Comment: Do you mean that you do not get this error with a different `batch_size`?

Comment: I tried different '[batch_size]' but same error, my initial thought was that the error come from come due to value of 'batch_size'

Comment: So apparently this is not the case.

Comment: are you comparing `>` somewhere?

Comment: What is the documentation of the `model.fit_generator` method? You are passing `augment`, which is an `ImageDataGenerator`, to it as second argument. Maybe an integer is expected there?

Answer (score 0):

Please check documentation for fit_generator (https://faroit.com/keras-docs/1.2.0/models/model/):

```
fit_generator(self, generator, samples_per_epoch, nb_epoch, verbose=1, callbacks=[], validation_data=None, nb_val_samples=None, class_weight={}, max_q_size=10, nb_worker=1, pickle_safe=False, initial_epoch=0)
```

The second argument is 'samples_per_epoch', which is int, but you are passing ImageDataGenerator instead. Hence the error message. I don't see why you need to pass 'augment' here. The following should work:

```
history = model.fit_generator(train, validation_data=valid, epochs=25, verbose=2, callbacks=[earlystopping])
```